# How to design a page in visual studio for each row from a datatable

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, visual-studio

Currently i am working on designing my website, the data are from my database.

My question is , if just say i have a data table with all my data for the events from my database displayed in a webpage,  but only with certain information such as **name of event, date, event place**. This function i know how to do, my problem is in addition to that,

I would like to create a link from the **name column** for each row, this **link** will that open a new web page designed with **all the details**(description , time of event , country) of the **specific event.**

So if just say the user click on the 5th row's event name link, the user would be directed to another page and a more detailed version of that specific event and only that event is visible to the user.

Anyone here knows what this process or procedure of this function is called as i am not sure how to go about it and what to search on the topic as well.

Thank You

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to create a link in HTML - or you don't know how to make that link open in another tab or window. If that is what you are looking for the html anchor tag is for the link & it's target attribute can be used to go to another page/tab (depending on browser). https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: Hi @PaulF sorry if my question is a little confusing, i know how to do both of what you mentioned, i just am ensure how to show the details of the row that has the link that has been clicked by the user to another new page and in this page it shows only that specific row details in a designed view like an event page . Hope i made it clear ! Thank You

Comment: Do these pages give you the information you are looking for : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx & https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hi @PaulF, i am not sure i think i am looking at how to do a single item page from a data table that the link from a certain column can generate . I hope this helps ! Thank you again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is fairly broad and it always better to have tried something and show. Please accept the following as guidelines to build a gridview in `ASP.NET`

[**ASP.NET GridView Basics and CRUD operations**](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Select-Insert-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-GridView-using-Entity-Framework-in-ASPNet.aspx) - This is a great example.

[**Open a Single Record View from a ASP.NET GridView click**](https://forums.asp.net/t/1196131.aspx?Opening%20a%20new%20window%20from%20a%20HyperLinkField%20of%20gridview%20in%20asp%20net%20)

There would be more efficient ways but this should cover the basics.

You could always create and WebApi REST service and use BootStrap or Angular Material to build the tables and use popup modals to show the single view...just a thought.

This is what you are looking for on the second link

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbRedirect" runat="server" Text="Show" OnClientClick="javascript:openWin("ShowPODetails.aspx?id=" + '<%# Eval("id")%>')"></asp:LinkButton>
```

You can pass the rest of the data as query string parameters

Comment: Hi @conradLotz thank you so much for the second link it was what i was looking for, i actually didn't  know the key word to search to start the function .... And after i got the key word i also found a link that would be useful to anyone that has the same question ! Thank you everyone ! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/display_data_items_and_details

Answer (score 0):

Create a standard ASP.NET project, create your database (either code first or database first), then use the wizards built into VS2015 to create both list pages and single item pages.  The code generated will exactly match your requirements.

See [asp.net](http://asp.net) for more details.

Comment: Hi @neil thank you for giving me the key word of single item pages!! This is what i meant :) Thanks loads i will research on it more now !

Comment: Do I get a tick for my answer :-)